# How to create a docker file for a Ballerina program which uses Java interoperability?

Tags: ballerina, ballerina-swan-lake, ballerina-java-interop

I have a Ballerina REST service which calls some Java methods from ballerina. I want to generate the Dockerfile for this application. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

We can use the [Ballerina Code-to-Cloud feature](https://ballerina.io/learn/code-to-cloud-deployment/) to generate the Dockerfile.

We can simply run the following command to generate the docker file:

```
$ bal build --cloud=docker
```

This will generate the Dockerfile in the following location: `target/docker/<package-name>`. This directory will have all the required JAR files including the ones used for Java interoperability.